# Вывод данных в csv файл на python

Tags: python, telegram, csv, telethon

Написав простенький парсер комментариев из определенного поста в telegram, пытаюсь полученные данные записать в csv файл, но в csv файл выводится только одна последняя строка. Пробовал сделать вывод с помощью pandas, но так и не смог от него добиться записи даже одной строки.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import csv

api_id = ##########
api_hash = '###################'
name = '#############'
chat = '############'

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    for message in client.iter_messages(chat, reply_to=220, reverse=True):
        print(message.date, message.sender_id, ':', message.text)

data = [message.date, message.sender_id, message.text]


with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(data[:3])
```

Comment: Ну вы все данные данные только через print выводите в цикле, а потом после цикла в data только последнюю строку сохраняете, ну и ее же сохраняете в csv. То что вы в коде написали, то и происходит.

Comment: Значит, мне необходимо переменную data перенести перед print и в print добавить file=data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы все сообщения только выводите через `print`, но никуда не сохряняете, потом в `data` записываете данные последнего сообщения, его же (это единственное сообщение) в csv и записываете (поэтому и получаете только одну строку).

Нужно либо получаемые сообщения добавлять в список по мере получения, потом циклом пройти по полученному списку, каждый его элемент записывать в csv как отдельную строку:

```
data = []

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    for message in client.iter_messages(chat, reply_to=220, reverse=True):
        print(message.date, message.sender_id, ':', message.text)
        data.append([message.date, message.sender_id, message.text])


with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Либо совместить получение сообщений и запись их в csv:

```
with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for message in client.iter_messages(chat, reply_to=220, reverse=True):
            print(message.date, message.sender_id, ':', message.text)
            writer.writerow([message.date, message.sender_id, message.text])
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, пришлось добавить with open('result.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n') as f: для работы с комментариями на русском языке)))

Comment: Ну, это уже детали. Если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым, для этого поставьте галку слева от ответа.